# Add a ToolBar to Frame using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a frame and add to it a toolbar at the page start and a statusbar at the bottom, and a desktop where I can show internal frames. but I just get an empty frame. What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks.

```
public class AdminStart extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JToolBar toolBar;
private JDesktopPane desktop;
private StatusBar statusBar;
private JPanel panel;

//this is a class that i created and extends JToolBar
private ToolBarAdmin miToolBar;

private String ID = null;
private String type = null;
private String state = null;

public AdministradorInicio(String ID, String tipo, String estado){

    super("Start");

    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    //setSize(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ, JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT);
    //setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.ID = ID;
    this.tipo = type;
    this.estado = state;

    toolBar = new JToolBar();
    miToolBar = new ToolBarAdmin();
    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    statusBar = new StatusBar();
    panel = new JPanel();

    for(int i = 0; i < miToolBar.toolBarTitles.length; i++){
        miToolBar.boton[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    toolBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    toolBar.setFloatable(false);
    toolBar.add(miToolBar);

    desktop.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    panel.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    panel.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


    add(panel);

    setVisible(true);     
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AdminStart("sdsd","sdsd","sdsd");
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hurting you:

```
setLayout(null);
```

When using `null` layouts, you the coder are completely responsible for specifying every component's position and size. You also end up with very rigid GUI's that are next to impossible to maintain or upgrade, and that *may* look good on one system and screen resolution, but which will likely look awful elsewhere. Also, as MadProgrammer would say, "pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design."  Solution, get rid of `setLayout(null)` and strive to avoid using `null` layouts.

Comment: you are right. Thanks!! I forgot to eliminate it after editing the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place control on a container with null layout - you have to set the bounds of the control first. For example:

```
panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

Otherwise this control will not be placed on your JFrame.